# asynchronously sending message to many tcp clients

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

i have a server program that accepts about 100000 tcp clients and sends data to them using asynchronous socket programming.to sending data to the clients i use a for loop that calls BeginSend for each client.
the problem is that when i start to send data to clients new clients can not get connected to the server until the sending is finished.
can any body help me to solve this problem?

```
//This is the Loop that calls Send Method
foreach (ClientInfo item in followers)
{
    Socketing.Send(item.state, JSONData);
}

public static void Send(StateObject state, String data)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    state.workSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
}
private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket socket = state.workSocket;
    int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(ar);
}
```

Comment: First show some code so we can figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: You need to queue those replies on another thread.  And also limit/throttle the number of ports you are using at one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single machine as a host for all your 100_000 clients, then they are using more than the 65_535 (less, actually) ports available on your system. You run out of system resources.

A connection is identified by 4 variables: src ip, src port, dst ip, dst ports. In the case I described you are running out of src ports.

Comment: 65535  is the limitation for ports. but there is no limitation for connections on a port

Comment: But the clients use different ports to connect, and the clients are most likely all on a single machine

Comment: when i disable the sending part of my code i can accept up to 200000 clients. but when the sending part is enabled accpeting new clients is stopped  while sending data

Comment: This answer seems to assume that all of the clients are on the same machine; I see nothing in the question that suggests that.

Comment: I took a guess, and the comment from Fariborz above seems to confirm my guess. He's using his own ports to send the data.

Comment: The sheer fact that they're complaining about what happens *when* they have 100000 or 200000 clients connected would seem to point *against* that, since you claim that they'd hit a hard limit before reaching that number of clients.

Comment: he says he's got 100_000 clients and some of them are waiting, there's no info about how many are actually waiting